# All functors "are" left adjoints, and applications?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, adjoint-functors, yoneda-lemma

Throughout this thread, let us assume smallness.

#### All functors "are" left adjoints

Let $D \xrightarrow{F} C$ be any functor, which induces

$$ D \xrightarrow{F} \hat{C}$$

by compositing the Yoneda embedding of $C$. There is a natural map going backward, but only to the free cocompletion of $D$.

$$ \hat{D} \xleftarrow{R} \hat{C}$$

which is defined by $R(c)(d) := \hat{C}(F(d),c)$. Then by the density theorem and the cocompleteness of $\hat{C}$, one can construct (by co-end) a left adjoint of $R$ that extends $F$

$$ \hat{D} \xrightarrow{L} \hat{C}.$$

So one can say that all functors "are" left adjoints, if they are happy to think of the free cocompletions as the natural extension

#### Explicit example

When $D$ is simply $\Delta$, then $\hat{D}$ is just $(sSet.)$. So any functor $F$ from $\Delta$ to $C$ admits an adjunction between $(sSet.)$ and $\hat{C}$. In particular, take $C = (Top.)$, which is cocomplete already, we have an adjunction

$$ (sSet.) \leftrightarrows (Top.). $$

In fact, this adjunction is a Quillen equivalence. This allows us to "model" topological space well by simplicial sets.

#### Question

But $D$ and $C$ can be quite general! And in any case, we have the adjunction. What are other examples that model one category with another well, beyond simplicial objects?

Comment: What do you mean by "model" ? The adjunction you give in the example is particularly nice *for homotopy theory* because it behaves well with weak equivalences; but apart from that is very far from a nice "model"

Comment: The key thing is to pick $D$ and $F$ so that the resulting "model" captures whatever aspects of $C$ you're interested in. As a non-example, we could always take $D$ to be the empty category and then $\hat D = *$ is indeed equipped with an adjunction to $C$, but it doesn't tell us anything useful.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Indeed.. I kept the question loose, but it was too loose. I have edited it. Hopefully it's better now.

Comment: It's a Quillen equivalence only for specific cosimplicial spaces, not all of them. Take the empty cosimplicial space for example... As far as I can tell, you have rediscovered a particular case of the concept of [Kan extension](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+extension). It's an interesting concept, yes, but I do not really see a satisfactory answer to your question other than "sure, sometimes it can yield a Quillen equivalence".

Comment: If you want to replace simplicial sets by other presheaves and still model homotopy types of CW-complexes, there is Grothendieck's theory of test categories. See http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_2005__301__R1_0/ and http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_2006__308__R1_0/ If you prefer an account in English, see Jardine's paper: https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/hha/content/vols/0008/0001/a003/index.php

Comment: In another direction, using presheaves, you may represent any homotopy theory determined by a combinatorial model category. See Dugger's paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870801920158  Lurie's theory of presentable $\infty$-categories gives the higher categorical counterpart of this. That will cover anything which is algebraic enough (sheaves of any kind of algebraic structure on any space/topos).

Comment: Isn't there a simpler description of $L$? Every object $x$ in $\hat{D}$ is a colimit $\varinjlim J$ where $J$ is a diagram in $D$. Then $L(x) = \varinjlim F(J)$ in $\hat{C}$.

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski Thanks for pointing that out! So I guess I could say $D$ can be replaced by any test categories. And by your work (mentioned in Jardine's paper), there are many of them. Cool! How about $C$? In general, can we understand something beyond the context of topology? Alex -- yes that's how's $L$ is constructed.

Comment: @Student $C$ may be any combinatorial model category (this is Dugger's paper I refer to above). This gives a wealth of examples which covers a huge class of homotopy theories defined by algebro-geometric considerations, much much beyond the homotopy theory of spaces.